# Render multiple components without changing route path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My goal is to render a `Component` without changing its url pathname. This `Component` is responsible to render three other child `components` when user clicks on the link. My code is working, but I don't think it is the right approach. My question is: What would be the best way of implementing this. Here's my code below:

```
const ComponentOne = () => {
  return (
    <div><h1>Component 1</h1></div>
  )
}

const ComponentTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div><h1>Component 2</h1></div>
  )
}

const ComponentThree = () => {
  return (
    <div><h1>Component 3</h1></div>
  )
}


class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            linkName: 'three'
        };
        this.renderList = <ComponentThree/>;
    }

    handleClick = (linkName) => {
        if (linkName === 'one') {
            this.renderList = <ComponentOne/>;
            this.setState({ linkName });
        } else if (linkName === 'two') {
            this.renderList = <ComponentTwo />;
            this.setState({ linkName  });
        } else {
            this.renderList = <ComponentThree />;
            this.setState({ linkName  });
        }
        return this.renderList;
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a 
            className={this.state.linkName === 'one' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick('one')}>
            Component 1
            </a></li>

          <li><a
            className={this.state.linkName === 'two' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick('two')}>
            Component 2
            </a></li>

          <li><a 
            className={this.state.linkName === 'three' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick('three')}>
            Component 3
            </a></li>

      </ul>
        {this.renderList}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

to better demonstrate here is a link to codepen:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mibragimov-the-sasster/pen/vYOyPGO)

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified by keeping the index in the state and then rendering based on the current index. Here's my slightly simplified solution:

https://codepen.io/olavih/pen/zYGobaV

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component 1</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component 2</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentThree = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component 3</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      linkIndex: 3
    };
  }

  handleClick = linkIndex => {
    this.setState({ linkIndex });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a
              className={this.state.linkIndex === 1 ? "active" : ""}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}
            >
              Component 1
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a
              className={this.state.linkIndex === 2 ? "active" : ""}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}
            >
              Component 2
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a
              className={this.state.linkIndex === 3 ? "active" : ""}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(3)}
            >
              Component 3
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        {this.state.linkIndex === 1 && <ComponentOne />}
        {this.state.linkIndex === 2 && <ComponentTwo />}
        {this.state.linkIndex === 3 && <ComponentThree />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag by default will reload the page.

You can pass the event object from onClick action (`onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e,'three')}`) to your handleClick method and in that method block reloading of the page with `e.preventDefault()`.

You can also use React Router to switch from using default HTML `<a>` to `<Link>`. Link component is rendering `<a>` but it does not reload the entire page after clicking.